# Complex type that still stores only as decimal in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

So, we have a model in ASP.net Core 2.0 MVC using Entity Framework, 
this model has decimal fields.

```
[Display(Name = "Total Cost")]
public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Total Bill")]
public decimal TotalBill { get; set; }
```

We then have another pair of properties that is for currency:

```
public CurrencyCode CostCurrency { get; set; }
public CurrencyCode BillCurrency { get; set; }
```

I have a return to display string based on Currency

```
public string TotalBillDisplay => 
    CurrencyDisplayFormat(CostCurrencey, TotalBill);

public string TotalCostDisplay => 
    CurrencyDisplayFormat(BillCurrencey, TotalCost);

private string CurrencyDisplayFormat(CurrencyCode currencyCode, decimal amount) 
{
    return currencyCode.PreSymbol 
    + Math.Round(amount, currencyCode.DecimalDigits) 
    + currencyCode.PostSymbol;
}
```

This feels a bit cumbersome to have 3 properties for each monetary value
1) decimal
2) currency
3) display

I know I can create a class that would have all three of these in, but then the Entity Framework migrations won't create decimal columns for `TotalCost` and `TotalBill`. They would need a relation to the new class (entity) making a complex mapping that seems a bit overkill.

Can I make an attribute of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

There are various options in a database for currency (Money, demical(x,y), etc.) which usually translate to decimal in C#. In one of my systems in which I deal in pounds only I use this formatting.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:£0.00}")]
```

Have a look to see if there are overloads for varying currency types you need

Comment: I have tried to use DisplayFormat attribute. Sadly cannot figure out how ,for example, to make that £ dynamic based on what's in the CostCurrency property, bear in mind both the property I am applying this attribute to, and the CostCurrency are in the same class.

Comment: An actual format can be achieved using  YourAmount.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB")); If you have the amount and the culture then this should work within a read-only property.

Comment: Sadly when I tried that in my view I get this:
"InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: DataAnnotations are really just an instruction. Suggest creating your own @Html.DisplayCurrencyFor method that does the operation. You can check the type and cast within this method which then allows you to output the required text